# Modify HTTP headers in Google App Engine Endpoints (Android)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I would like to add custom headers to the HTTP package sent to an Endpoint. I've read that I can access the raw HTTP data in the Endpoint method (by adding a HttpServletRequest parameter). What I am looking for is a solution (or a hack) to access and modify the data being sent by the (Android) client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Http headers can be modified like this. I use this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints) as example. Since it's one of the Google's example.

Read it and find **EndpointsAsyncTask** you can use **GoogleClientRequestInitializer** for this. inside

***public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException***

you can set headers like this.

```
HttpHeaders headers = abstractGoogleClientRequest.getRequestHeaders();
headers.setDate(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
headers.set("MyCustomHeader", "HeaderValue");
abstractGoogleClientRequest.setRequestHeaders(headers);
```

In above code setDate() can be used to set Date header and set() method has been used to set my own header that can be read from server side. I have used calendar class to get date but Calendar class initialization is not shown here.

I have also write a note on my blog to show how it's actually reside in the method. if you like read [that](http://nipunswritings.blogspot.com/2015/07/include-httpheaders-to-google-cloud-api.html) too.

Comment: As I recall we ended up using a HttpRequestInitializer as 3rd parameter of the Api.Builder constructor, but yours seem to work as well

Comment: Good to hear that you have found some way to do that. Yeah my solutions works. I have tested it for use hmac with google cloud endpoints. I have written the full example for that in my blog.