# Add custom headers to Cloud Endpoints call in iOS (Swift) using iOS client library

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

How do you add custom headers when executing API calls with Cloud Endpoints in an iOS app (with Swift)?

Here is the same question answered for Android, but I cannot find an iOS example anywhere:

[Modify HTTP headers in Google App Engine Endpoints (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532527/modify-http-headers-in-google-app-engine-endpoints-android)

Thanks!

Comment: Does Google Cloud Endpoints have an iOS framework you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the additionalHTTPHeaders property associated with each GTLService base class. For e.g.

```
var service = GTLServiceTictactoe()
service.retryEnabled = YES
service.additionalHTTPHeaders = ["my custom header name " : "my custom header value"]
....
```

Here is the description of this property from documentation

```
/**
 *  Any additional HTTP headers for this queries executed by this service.
 *
 *  Individual queries may have additionalHTTPHeaders specified as well.
 */
@property(atomic, copy, nullable) NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *additionalHTTPHeaders;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with google app engine but I took a look at their iOS example app [tic tac toe](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-ios). So there is nothing complicated there. They are using standard iOS HTTP request.

you can find the following lines [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-ios/blob/afda19a9e7bfc0a1dcb460e9f111fe8f515fc44b/TicTacToeSample/GTMOAuth2SignIn.m)

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:infoURL];

NSString *userAgent = [auth userAgent];
[request setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[request setValue:@"no-cache" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cache-Control"];
```

after adding the header to `NSMutableURLRequest` then you can use this request with `NSURLConnection`.

so if you need something additional you can add it there. [here is a good tutorial if you are new to iOS development.](http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/)